# How many labeld trees (specific labels) on 7 vertices with 4 leafs exactly (specific ones)

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

the Question : all trees T such that $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7\}$ the proper (1,..,7) is the labels
Find : number of trees such that 1,2,3,4 exactly leafs
.

(By the way in my course the graph's are undirected)\

Solotion:(**this is my first attempt**)\

We have 4 verticies left than
$  4! $ and we have the possebilities for degree 2 to 3
Then i need to divide by the number of repetitions and also count each case ?
I a little bit confused about this question \

**Update:**
the length of the proper code is 5 and we want 567 one of them is degree 4 or two of them degree 3
Then :

$ 3\choose1$  $4!\div 3!$$ + $$3\choose2$ $4!\div 2!2!$

Comment: Thinking about Prüfer codes is the correct way to go. You want to count sequences of length $5$, where none of the symbols $\{1,2,3,4\}$ appear, and where all of $\{5,6,7\}$ appear. E.g, $[6,7,7,5,6]$. You can count these directly, case by case, or use the principle of inclusion exclusion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you’re calling the *proper code* is actually the **Prüfer** code or Prüfer sequence.

The number of times that a vertex label appears in the Prüfer sequence is one less than the degree of the vertex, so labels $1,2,3$, and $4$ won’t appear at all; all $5$ labels in the Prüfer sequence must come from the set $\{5,6,7\}$. A tree with $7$ vertices has $6$ edges, so the sum of the degrees of its vertices must be $12$; the $4$ leaves account for $4$ of that total, so the sum of the degrees of the other $3$ vertices must be $12-4=8$. (Alternatively, the other $3$ vertices appear a total of $5$ times in the Prüfer sequence, so the sum of their degrees must be $5+3=8$.) If their degrees are $a,b$, and $c$, we must have $a+b+c=8$ and $a,b,c\ge 2$, and the only possibilities are $4+2+2$ and $3+3+2$. Thus, either we have one vertex of degree $4$ and two of degree $2$, or we have two of degree $3$ and one of degree $2$.

In the first case there are $3$ choices for the vertex of degree $4$ and $\binom53$ choices for the $3$ places in which it appears in the Prüfer sequence; the $2$ vertices of degree $2$ can appear in either order in the remaining $2$ positions in the Prüfer sequence, so there are altogether

$$3\cdot\binom53\cdot2=3\cdot10\cdot2=60$$

labelled trees in this case.

In the second case there are $3$ choices for the vertex of degree $2$ and $5$ choices for place in the Prüfer sequence in which it appears. There are then $\binom42$ choices for the $2$ places in which the lower-numbered vertex of degree $3$ appears, and the other vertex of degree $3$ must then occupy the remaining $2$ positions. Thus, there are altogether

$$3\cdot5\cdot\binom42=3\cdot5\cdot6=90$$

labelled trees in this case, for a grand total of $60+90=150$ labelled trees with the desired properties.

Comment: now i fully understand my mistakes. i could first systematically determine with handshake theorem and n-1 edges beacuse we have 7 Verticies , and than we continue to check the possible deg(v) with simple equation , and we check  each independent case and be the sum principle we add them . thank you !

Comment: first term you wrote 4 it's suppose to be 3 , no ?(before $5\choose3$)

Comment: @cisco_guy: You’re welcome! And thanks for catching that typo; you’re absolutely right that it should have been a $3$.